# How to word wrap when printing through printdocument using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printdocument

I am trying to print receipt in EPSON TM-T82 ReceiptSA4 thermal printer (80mm roll). But while printing the whole string is not wrapped in the next line.

```
Private Sub prnLDocument_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles prnLDocument.PrintPage
        Dim sInvNo As String = "Explored the DrawString method and couldn't figure out how to do the automatic word wrap. Can you please. After setting the printer name, call IsValid to determine if the printer name is recognized as a valid printer on the system."

        Dim InvTitleFont As Font = New Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(sInvNo, InvTitleFont, BlueBrush, 5, 20)
End Sub

Private Sub BillPrint()
        Try
            prnLDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "EPSON TM-T82 ReceiptSA4" 
            prnLPreview.Document = Me.prnLDocument
            prnLPreview.ShowDialog()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BillPrint()
End Sub
```

Required help how to solve this printing issue.

Comment: If you give it a rectangle to print in rather than a point to start printing at, it will wrap the text for you: [DrawString(String, Font, Brush, RectangleF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawString_System_String_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Drawing_RectangleF_).

Answer (score 0):

```
sInvNo.MaximumSize = New Size(100, 0)
sInvNo.AutoSize = True
```

change "100" to what suits you best :)

Comment: I have taken sInvNo as a string. Here mentioned code given an error.

Comment: i did it with a label, just add a label to your form, and then change your label's text by code, or you will have to add manual breaks inside your string like so: "hello" & (vb.newline or vbCrLf) & "world"